# Convert TimedeltaIndex to DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I'm trying to extract times from a TimedeltaIndex object.
I tried using `pd.to_datetime()` but got the following error:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> times = pd.timedelta_range(start='10:00:00', end='12:00:00', freq='min')
>>> pd.to_datetime(times)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 812, in to_datetime
    result = convert_listlike(arg, format, name=arg.name)
  File ".../python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 371, in _convert_listlike_datetimes
    arg, _ = maybe_convert_dtype(arg, copy=False)
  File ".../python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/datetimes.py", line 2123, in maybe_convert_dtype
    raise TypeError(f"dtype {data.dtype} cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]")
TypeError: dtype timedelta64[ns] cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]
```

I ended up using the following line but I am hoping there is a more elegant solution:
`(pd.to_datetime(0) + times).time`

Comment: It's a little unclear because the two are fundamentally different objects. For instance, you can have a timedelta of 49 hours. But with your current method you'd be considering that `datetime.time(1, 0)`, which might be correct, but might also not make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert TimeDeltaIndex to datetime by first converting it to integer.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

times = pd.timedelta_range(start='10:00:00', end='12:00:00', freq='min')
pd.to_datetime(times.astype(np.int64)).time
```

This gives the same output as the **(pd.to_datetime(0) + times).time**

Comment: Yeah I read something about **astype** but couldn't figure out how to make use of it in this case. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, if the answer worked for you can you accept it as a accepted answer? Thanks!